# How to get id in Middleware when i use user()

Tags: laravel, relational-database, laravel-middleware

I have a relationship between users and roles. In middleware, I need to get roles to check if the role is 1 or 2. However, I get the following error.

> "Trying to get property 'role_id' of non-object."

I am sure I have id 1 in role_id.

**User Model**

```php
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth()->check() && $request->user()->role_id == 1) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement's logic is mistakenly checking if the user is logged **out**, while also checking the user's roles. If `Auth::check()` is `false`, then the user is not logged in and `$request->user()` will return `null`.

Removing the `!` from the conditional will fix the error you're receiving.

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth()->check() && $request->user()->role_id == 1) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

However, this will **allow all guests to proceed**, which you may not want. Assuming you want the middleware to only allow logged-in users with a specific role to proceed, use a more white-listed approach like this:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Role ID 2 has permission to proceed
    if (Auth()->check() && $request->user()->role_id == 2) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    // Everyone else should go back, including logged-in users and guests.
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: i use this solveing but i have this error now  "This page isn’t working"

Answer (score 0):

[Can't comment so I'm making a post.]

Aken already answered you but I'd suggest one more thing. Don't use 1 or 2 as ID's but constants:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth()->check() && $request->user()->role_id == ADMIN) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

You don't even need the comments for this one. Maybe even better:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth()->check() && $request->user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

but you need to implement it on your own.